# Windows shows only 29GB of HDD available on a new laptop?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I bought new Fujitsu Ultrabook, that has a space of 500 GB, but my C-Drive is showing 29 GB only, I don't know what is the issue.

I went to the disk management, there I found 2 disk, disk 0 basic with unallocated space of 465 GB and Disk 1 with one partition of 29 GB:

[image: File manager]

How to recover the full storage for C-drive without re-installing Windows 8? I can't opt for this option as I have some original software installed in it.

I am not a technical person, what would be a step by step process to recover the C-drive space?

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear, but I would strongly suggest reinstalling Windows. 29 GB simply isn't enough for the OS, you will fill it up and performance will start to suffer. An SSD of this size is usually meant to act as a cache for a larger HDD, and perhaps it's an error on the part of the manufacturer that your computer was not set up this way. You could also try contacting Fujitsu customer support about this issue.

Comment: @Indrek That's what I thought too, but I think this is actually a fairly common setup for Ultrabooks - of course, Windows *must* be properly configured by the manufacturer to use the secondary HDD for everything else, but that's not the case here - it wasn't even allocated. I think a call to Fujitsu is also warranted, at least to let them know they screwed up somewhere, and a customer is having to work his/her way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not recover the space from **drive C** because *you never lost it* - your laptop model looks to be equipped with an SSD, and an HDD.

The usual setup for that kind of hardware is that the OS is installed on the faster SSD, and everything else goes on the slower HDD. Why your HDD is unallocated, and thus, unavailable is beyond me - could be an error on the manufacturer's part.

Anyway, here's my suggestion:

- Right click on the unallocated space, and click `New Simple Volume`
- This will start a Wizard. Click `Next` to continue.
- You will be asked to specify the size (Simple Volume Size in MB). I suggest *inputting the max disk space*, because 500GB nowadays is not much.
- Click `Next` to continue.
- You will be asked to assign a Drive Letter. Windows is smart enough not to assign a Drive Letter that is already in use, so *you can leave this as is*, and click `Next` again.
- You will be asked for the formatting options - again, Windows sets some defaults, so *you can leave this as is*. Click `Next` to continue.
- Click `Finish` and you should see a new drive, called "New Simple Volume".
- Optionally, you can relocate your files (Documents, Downloads, Music, Videos, etc) to **drive D**. Getting this to work similar to Windows' 'stock' configuration will take some work. It's not too technical, just a little tedious. If you want more information about the latter, see [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-move-windows-7-personal-folders-my-documents-another-drive.htm).

Comment: I tried creating simple volume for the Disk 0 with unallocated space and it created E drive but when I tried to extend the C-drive the extended option was greyed mean disable.

Comment: You can't extend one `physical` drive on to another, without using some complex RAID solution, or some other software. Basically, Your C-Drive is physically separated from your D-Drive - you can only extend the C to the D when both are from the same physical hard drive.

Comment: But, I am working and I need to save my work due to low space I can't save it. Is there anyway I can use space that is available but not showing and save my work on it.

Comment: Which is why I suggested you relocate your work to Drive D, which has 500 or so GB. Again, Windows should've been configured to do this, but for some reason, it's not. What kind of work do you do, and where do you save it?

Comment: I am working on Word Doc. and need to save bigger PDF files and writing work.

Comment: Also any software I install it save on C-drive which reduces its space , suggest a way that whatever I install wont go in the C-drive.

Comment: Should I follow the step you have written above? will this help

Comment: Okay, regarding your work, for a quick and easy (albeit dirty) way to save C-drive space, simply copy over your work to the D-drive, and work on it from there. For your second comment, what software have you installed already? I'm afraid there's no other way but to *uninstall* them, and then *install* them, making sure that their directory points to the D-drive. When installing the software, they often ask which directory to be installed in, and they usually say `C:\Program Files\etc\etc`. Simply replace the `C:` with `D:` and you should be okay.

Comment: Okay, but the simple volume from allocated space is creating E drive is that ok? shall I go for it?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: No problem. If it's not too much trouble, and if you have no further questions, mind marking my answer this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Don't know how to mark

Comment: At the top left of my post, there's an up and down arrow with a number in between. If you move your mouse below the down arrow, a green "Check" should appear. Clicking that means you've accepted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it follows from  your image, your drive C indeed has only 30Gb capacity with about 400Mb reserved for some recovery information. There is no way to extend the capacity of this drive.

However, as you have probably noticed, there is a second drive installed with 465Gb of unallocated space. You can right click on it to allocate some disks and then format them. Once this is done, the disks can be assigned certain drive letters and used for storage.

Unfortunately it is not possoble to merge the space from two physical devices into one, hence you will only hae 30 Gb for your system files and you might want to change your configuration in the way that apps and programs are installed on a secondary drive. This is somewhat tricky and you better seek some professional help if you are not sure.

Comment: So, what should I do? Shall I take help from professionals?

Answer (score 1):

Your notebook is equipped with a 32 GB SSD. This is where Windows is installed. Whatever drove the manufacturer to do this, I cannot fathom. It's rather insane.

The 500 GB drive is the unpartitioned space you're seeing.

Comment: So, what you suggest?

Comment: Create a partition (right click -> New Simple Volume) and be done with it. Everything else entails moving Windows away from the IMHO way too small SSD.

Comment: will it increase the storage of C-drive?

Comment: No, that's impossible, as the others already stated.

Comment: Oh means! i can't have enough storage for C-drive. Is there no way I can have the storage. Because when I bought Fujitsu they claim with the storage of 500 GB, was that a big lie?

Comment: No, they're not lying! That unallocated HDD space can be used as a new partition.

Comment: return the laptop and buy a proper one